# When is it appropriate to use result.success(null)?

Tags: java, android, flutter

When implementing platform specific code the Android API relies on the `MethodChannel` class.
More specifically on the `onMethodCall(MethodCal, Result)` method.
The `Result` interface has three methods pretty self-explanatory, but I'm having troubles to understand when it's the case to use `result.success(null)` when the Dart method has a return type `Future<void>`.
So, because of the void type, it's not clear to me if I should include `result.success(null)` at the end of my implementation.
If not, what are those cases where it's required? I'm not able to find any reference in the official docs.
To provide more context, let's imagine a Dart method like this one:

```dart
static Future<void> openSettings() async {
    _channel.invokeMethod('openSettings');
}
```

And the native code like the following:

```java
@Override
public void onMethodCall(@NonNull MethodCall call, @NonNull Result result) {
    switch (call.method) {
        ...
        case "openSettings":
            openSettings();
            result.success(null);   // <--- is this required ?
            break;
        ...
    }
}
```

Commenting out the `result.success(null)` does not produce any (apparent) difference in the program flow, then why passing a `null` value to the `success` method is allowed?
Quoting from the [official Flutter API](https://api.flutter.dev/javadoc/io/flutter/plugin/common/MethodChannel.Result.html#success-java.lang.Object-):

> The result, possibly null

Comment: `"When is it appropriate to use result.success(null)?"` - well, the method that returns some object (String for example) could return a null value - thats why `null` is allowed - however in your case when `void` is returned you dont have to use `success` method at all

Comment: Thank you for explaining. If you provide this as an answer, I'll make sure to mark it as accepted.